# Gstreamer custom videosink for playbin

Tags: python-3.x, gstreamer

I'm trying to create a custom videosink for playbin in gstreamer 1.6.3

The final idea is to have some videomixer inside the videosink to be able to do.. stuff.

At the moment i would like to simply create a custom Bin that incapsulates a videosink.

The relevant parts of the code at the moment are:

```
def get_videomix_bin(self):
    mix_bin = Gst.Bin.new('sink')

    sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('glimagesink')
    gp = Gst.GhostPad.new('vs', sink.get_static_pad('sink'))
    mix_bin.add(sink)

    mix_bin.add_pad(gp)

    return mix_bin


def get_pipeline(self, videosink):
    """A basic playbin pipeline pipeline"""
    self.pipeline = Gst.ElementFactory.make('playbin')
    videosink = self.get_videomix_bin()

    self.pipeline.set_property('video-sink', videosink)

    self.fireEvent('pipeline-created')
```

This code is part of a bigger software that I cannot post whole. But if i comment out the self.pipeline.set_property('video-sink', videosink) part, it works, so i tend to think that the problem is somwhere there.

It... well it basically don't work. The pipeline won't start.

At GST_DEBUG=2 i get this warning

```
0:00:00.758103367 15560 0x7f81000050a0 WARN            uridecodebin gsturidecodebin.c:939:unknown_type_cb:<uridecodebin0> warning: No decoder available for type 'video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3.1, profile=(string)main, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe1001c674d401fe8802802dd80b501010140000003004000000c83c60c448001000468ebaf20, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)25/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, parsed=(boolean)true'.
```

Comment: That error means you do not have decode element for h264 format, so playbin cannot decode. Install gst-libav can solve it.

Comment: If i uncomment the custom video sink, it works. Therefore all the decoders are installed.

Comment: You say "it works", did you see the video, or you just see the program run and exit without video? If you did see the video, check what video sink is using. If it is the later case, pipline probably not work.  
BTW, just notice that you set a **bin** to `video-sink` property. According to its manual, you should set a **GstElement** there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the ghostpad on the videosink bin "sink", not "vs". The pad names are part of the API, and sink elements are expected to have a pad called "sink".